# "git remote" doesn't display origin. Why?

Tags: git, github

I cloned a remote repo, but when I type `git remote` It doesn't display `origin`. Why?

```
User@200x300SEREGA MINGW64 /d/git (master) 
$ git clone https://github.com/speresunko/speresunko.github.io 
Cloning into 'speresunko.github.io'... 
remote: Counting objects: 6, done. 
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done. 
remote: Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), done. 

User@200x300SEREGA MINGW64 /d/git (master) 
$ git remote

User@200x300SEREGA MINGW64 /d/git (master) 
$
```

Comment: Thank you. i'll be more attentive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the line  `Cloning into`. It said that the repo was cloned into a folder called `speresunko.github.io`.
Navigate to this folder and your cloned repo will be there. The `git remote` command will work as desired in this folder.